# Verilog: Is the following code going to make a race condition?

Tags: verilog, race-condition

I'm trying to make a pipeline processor using Verilog HDL. I realized that there are maybe some race conditions somewhere in my code. So I'm going to write a sudo code and would like to ask you about if there is a race condition within and how to avoid it :

```
module A(input wire reset, input wire clock, output reg a_reg_o);
   always @(posedge clock)
   begin
      if(reset == 1'h1)
      begin
         a_reg_o = 1'h0;
      end
      else
      begin
         a_reg_o = 1'h1;
      end
   end
endmodule

module B(input wire reset, input wire clock, input a_i);
   reg b;

   always @(posedge clock)
   begin
      if(reset == 1'h1)
      begin
         b = 1'h0;
      end
      else
      begin
         if(a_i == 1'h1)
         begin
            b = 1'h1;
         end
         else
         begin
            b = 1'h0;
         end
      end
   end
endmodule

module Main(input wire reset, input wire clock);
   wire a_o;
   A a(reset, clock, a_o);
   B b(reset, clock, a_o)
endmodule
```

So imagine I trigger reset signal. After the first positive edge of clock the register a_reg_o is going to be 0 and register b from module B also is going to be 0 (No race conditions yet). Now I release the reset button and let it to be negative. On the next positive edge of the clock the register a_reg_o is going to be 1, but what about register b from module B ? Is it going to be :
1. Zero, Because it didn't see the a_i changes yet.
2. It depends on the modules (A and B) total delay ( i.e. a race condition).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is why there a non-blocking (NBA) assignments in Verilog. The coding rule is whenever there are multiple processes (in this case, multiple `always` blocks) accessing the same signal (`a_o`) synchronized to the same event (`@posdege clock`) where one process writes and another process reads, you need to use and NBA `<=` assignment to write to the signal.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. There are still two questions : 1. I should use NBA only for writing blocks ? 2. Is the race condition only a simulation problem or it's also a physical implementation (post synthesis) issue ? I mean is it possible to have a different behavior due to delay of different paths, after synthesis ?

Comment: You should use NBA's according to the rule I just gave, otherwise use a normal assignment. In RTL the translates to using NBAs for the output of sequential logic. Unfortunately, you can have a race in your RTL the does not exist in the physical implementation and a race in the physical implementation that does not exist in the RTL.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there can be a race condition, because you won't know whether the net `a_o` is first driven by module A and then captured by module B or vice versa.

So you should use the Non Blocking Assignment for this, as that will ensure that no matter which module gets executed, the module B will always have the previous value of net `a_o`.

You can find more about this Non Blocking Assignments with following link. http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2000SJ_NBA.pdf